# Intersection of an open and closed set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have $A\cap B=C$ where $A$ is closed and $B$ and $C$ are open. Does this imply anything else about the sets or their limit points?

My intuition says it might imply something like $A\subset B$, but that's usually wrong when it comes to topological spaces.

Comment: If the space has the discrete topology, then all sets are clopen (both open and closed), so $A$ and $B$ can be completely arbitrary.

Comment: Ah you're right. What if we make further topological assumptions.

Comment: $C$ is clopen in $B$, so if $B$ is connected, then either $C=\varnothing$, or $A\supseteq B$.

Comment: Brian, I think this is what I'm looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: You’re very welcome. I hope that it does help: it was just the first interesting case that happened to come to mind!